# Change current browser size when on ready function or in button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to resize the browser size when the URL enter or in query ready function?

window.resize() function is work on when loading a new browser. But I need to change the current working browser size to change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize browser to specified pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026011/resize-browser-to-specified-pixel)

Comment: Offtopic: Basic rule of web development, don't change the browser size of the **current** browser, keep in mind browsers nowadays are multitabs also it is irritanting when a website forces you to view in a fixed size.. Window popups on the other side is a other story..